# Add preload attribute in wp_enqueue_script

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to add attributes in :

```
<script src='http://localhost/projects/eviden/wp-content/themes/evidian/assets/build/fonts/Montserrat-VariableFont_wght.ttf' id='preload-custom-font-js'></script>
```

but it's not getting added, not sure what went wrong:

```
function my_style_loader_tag_filter($html, $handle)
    {
        if ($handle === 'preload-custom-font') {
            return str_replace(
                "id='preload-custom-font-js'",
                "rel='preload' as='font' type='font/ttf' id='preload-custom-font-js'",
                $html
            );
        }
        return $html;
    }
add_filter('style_loader_tag', array($this, 'my_style_loader_tag_filter'), 10, 2);
```

I want to add rel='preload' as='font' type='font/ttf' in the script tag getting rendered.

Comment: Maybe you should use the `script_loader_tag` filter for _script_ files, and not `style_loader_tag` ...?

Answer (score 0):

```
function preload_custom_font($html, $handle, $href, $media) {
    if ($handle === 'preload-custom-font') {
        $html = str_replace(
            "<script src='$href' id='preload-custom-font-js'></script>",
            "<link rel='preload' as='font' type='font/ttf' href='$href' id='preload-custom-font-js' crossorigin='anonymous'>",
            $html
        );
    }
    return $html;
}
add_filter('style_loader_tag', 'preload_custom_font', 10, 4);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).